# String.Contains int?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, int

I am wondering how to write this part of the code ..

I would like to say that if the name of my folder contains R + whatever the int ( R1, R52 etc ), then I do an action.

This is what I try to use :

```
 if(f.Name.Contains("R" + int))
 {

 }
```

Comment: int is a type, not a format.. You can use a regex or maybe check if the second char if a number type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (f.Name.Contains ("R" + Convert.ToString(i)))
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much identical to the first answer provided.

Answer (score 8):

This is a good time to [use Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx)

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(f.Name, @"R\d")) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Actually the `+` is not needed.

Comment: @Msonic - Not really, the above regex says "this contains an R followed immediately by a digit", there is no condition where \d+ would succeed where \d would not

Answer (score 2):

Use the string representation of the int?

```
if(f.Name.Contains("R" + i.ToString()))
{

}
```

Or do you want to match any integer? You'll have to run a regex for that. Probably just "R\d+" as the expression.

Comment: `i` is now known a priori, it's an arbitrary number.

Comment: The `ToString()` is not necessary.

Comment: I read it as matching a particular int that was retrieved from previous code. Perhaps I was incorrect.

Comment: @Alexander: Right, it's a bit ambiguous. I was referring to "whatever the int", but that's not clear at all.

Comment: @CodeInChaos No, but it's not incorrect either. I like to be more explicit when answering questions from those who appear to not have as good a grasp on the syntax.

Comment: @NiklasB. What do you mean by "whatever the int"? Any integer value?

Comment: @Alexander: That's how I interpreted it (it's a quote from the question), but as I said, you're right that it's ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Regex:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(f.Name, "R[0-9]"))
{
   // This will only execute if the String starts with R
   // and is followed by 1 or more numbers
}
```

Comment: "contains", not "starts with".

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
if(r.Name.StartsWith("R"))
{

}
```

Comment: "contains", not "starts with". Also the character after the `R` has to be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use switch :

```
string caseSwitch = f.Name;
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case "R1": 
        Console.WriteLine("Case R1");
        break;
    case "R2":
        Console.WriteLine("Case R2");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
        break;
}
```

Comment: That is a really bad idea, it has no scalability

Comment: He also wants a 'Contains' operation, not a StartsWith

Comment: I'd like to see the version that scales up to `R52`, as stated in the question :) That'd be a strong case of WTF. By the way, there is no hint at all that the taken action should be different for the different numbers, rather to the contrary...